# Does Django has Hazelcast support? What would be the configuration?

Tags: python, django, django-models, memcached, hazelcast

Requirement is to use Hazelcast cache running on some other machine for the Django application we been developing. Could you please advise what would be the config and if any module needs to be installed?

Note: I'm using memache already. But need to use hazelcast instead for project requirement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are looking for a pure memcache replacement, see [the doc](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html-single/index.html#memcache-client)

Comment: Thank you! Then is it just below change in Django settings.py


CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND':'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
        'LOCATION':'127.0.0.1:11211 <MACHINE DETAILS HAZELCAST IS RUNNING>',
    }
}

Answer (score 2):

There is a Hazelcast Python client but since I'm not a Python developer I can't really tell if it is hard or easy to integrate it into Django, however most certainly possible :)

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/hazelcast-python-client